# How to make an alias in .htaccess to hide visually the directory path of the URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, alias

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate but I just don't know how to find the answer to this simple problem.

So I have this local page - WP Page:
`https://localhost/mrdigital/alias-links-pdf/`

And the code below is the model - The template file used for the /alias-links-pdf/ page.

Inside the template file there are two links. Both links generates two different PDF files when clicked to be downloaded. (one file with parameter and another without parameter)

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header(); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    <section>

        <div class="page_book_title">
            Book Genres - What Kinds of Books Are There?<br>
            There are very different types of books - Let's tell you which ones!
        </div>

        <div class="page_book_pdf">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://localhost/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360">PDF One </a></li>
            <li><a href="https://localhost/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php">PDF Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I need to create an Alias for both links or both URLs because when hovering the mouse, it display the whole file directory. The folder are exposed and this is not wished.

I need to use something like this, so when the user hover the pointer, we see an Alias.
This is a url route as well.
`https://localhost/mrdigital/items/`

Then I tried to use the lines below in the .htaccess, but there is something wrong with the code. The page get into a loop.

```
# BEGIN Code
RewriteRule ^mrdigital/pdf-one$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360 [L]
RewriteRule ^mrdigital/pdf-two$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php [QSD,L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /mrdigital/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /mrdigital/index.php [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/page-aliasurl.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

What should be the simplest way to this alias ?

Is it even possible to make rewrite for two different files in the same .htaccess file?

I appreciat any help.

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located? Is it in the document root, or in the `/mrdigital` subdirectory?

Comment: Hello @MrWhite,
Thank you so much for the help!. I will do the modification and I give you a feedback.

This is the file path.
C:\xampppserver\htdocs\mrdigital\.htaccess

Comment: I edited the block of code in the question (.htaccess block) again, so you can see how I am using it.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/page-aliasurl.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

This unconditionally rewrites *everything* that maps to a file (or directory) to `page-aliasurl.php` - so yes, this is going break *everything*. A rule like this is also in the wrong place - it needs to go before the rewrite to the front-controller. (However, what is `page-aliasurl.php`? You make no reference to this in your question.)

Try it like this...

> ```
> <li><a href="https://localhost/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360">PDF One </a></li>
> <li><a href="https://localhost/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php">PDF Two</a></li>
> ```

Change your anchors so they link to the desired canonical URLs of your two PDFs. For example:

```
<li><a href="https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-one">PDF One </a></li>
<li><a href="https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-two">PDF Two</a></li>
```

`/mrdigital/pdf-one` and `/mrdigital/pdf-two` should not be routes in WordPress - they will be overridden anyway if they are. If you are performing this rewrite using `.htaccess` then this operates outside of WordPress.

Then create the following rewrites at the top of your *root* `.htaccess` file, *before* the existing directives. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^mrdigital/pdf-one$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360 [L]
RewriteRule ^mrdigital/pdf-two$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php [QSD,L]
```

This uses the `RewriteBase /mrdigital/` directive that is already set later in the file.

The first rule internally rewrites the request from `/mrdigital/pdf-one` to `/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360` and from `/mrdigital/pdf-two` to `/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php` (no URL parameter). The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag on the second rule only ensures that the first PDF cannot be accessed by requesting `/mrdigital/pdf-two?key=1360`.

If, however, your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/mrdigital` subdirectory (not the document root) then remove the `mrdigial/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* of both the above rules.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
> ```

If your `.htaccess` file is in the document root then you should change the above directive to read:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^mrdigital/index\.php$ - [L]
> ```

---

**UPDATE:**

> This is the file path. `C:\xampppserver\htdocs\mrdigital\.htaccess`

Since the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/mrdigital` subdirectory then, as stated above, you need to "remove the `mrdigial/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern* of both rules".

In summary, your code should look like this:

(Although if this is WordPress, then you should avoid editing the code between in the WordPress code block.)

```
# Rewrite specific PDF documents
RewriteRule ^pdf-one$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360 [L]
RewriteRule ^pdf-two$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php [QSD,L]

# BEGIN Code
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#RewriteBase /mrdigital/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L] 

# I do not know what this is trying to do?
# It is certainly incorrect in its format and placement in the file.
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/page-aliasurl.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

NB: I commented out the `RewriteBase` directive - it is not required if the `.htaccess` file itself is inside the `/mrdigital` subdirectory. And I remove the `/mrdigital/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string also - again, this is not required if the `.htaccess` file is in the subdirectory.

Comment: Hello @mrwhite, 
I have edited my question. 

However, what is page-aliasurl.php? You make no reference to this in your question :: 
Answer: This is the model - The template file used for the /alias-links-pdf/ page

Comment: Well, I did the modifications. ::
1° - I put the two lines in the very beginning of the .htaccess file  ::  
RewriteRule ^mrdigital/pdf-one$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360 [L]
::
RewriteRule ^mrdigital/pdf-two$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php [QSD,L]

Comment: 2° - I tried to access the files in the browser as if they would be a route, but I get the 404 error page. ::
https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-one  ::

https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-two  ::

This page does not exist.

Comment: 3° - Just to be sure that those lines would be something important, I commented the lines and tested each one.

:: RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
:: RewriteRule . /mrdigital/index.php [L]
:: but when I click on the page links 
PDF One :: 
PDF Two :: 
I got the 404 page. :: 
This page does not exist.

What should I try now please?

Comment: @TobitheDev Note that I state at the bottom of my answer: "If, however, your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/mrdigital` subdirectory (not the document root) then remove the `mrdigital/` prefix on the `RewriteRule` pattern of both the above rules." - it seems from your comment on your question that your `.htaccess` is indeed inside the `/mrdigital` subdirectory, so you need to update those two rules accordingly. But that last rule regarding `page-aliasurl.php` doesn't make much sense?

Comment: All right. So I did this for both RewriteRule in the beginning of the file and I receive error 404 - Object not found! on the browser ::
RewriteRule ^pdf-one$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360 [L]
:: 
RewriteRule ^pdf-two$ wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php [QSD,L]

Comment: @TobitheDev I've updated my answer, to include a summary of the directives.

Comment: @TobitheDev To clarify, you are requesting `/mrdigital/pdf-one` and `/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php` exists as a physical script that presumably generates the PDF response?

Comment: yes. There is a physical script that generates the PDF. For this to happen, I use the **mPDF Library v.8.0** 
I made the modifications that you made and suggest, but now, I do not have access to the page where we can see the links that I click and the PDF files are generated.
**https://localhost/mrdigital/alias-links-pdf/**
Error 404, this page does not exist.
:: When I try to access the files direct in the browser, I receive the 404 page error as well.
:: **https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-one**
:: **https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-two**
Error 404, this page does not exist.

Comment: I should've made that since we started this topic. here is the whole htaccess file that I am using. ::
[htaccess settings](https://regexr.com/6c0sj)

Comment: @TobitheDev `localhost/mrdigital/alias-links-pdf` - this is presumably a WordPress page? What if you request `/mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360` directly? I see no reason for the 404s. Nothing ew've changed here should prevent `/mrdigital/alias-links-pdf` from working? In your "whole htaccess file" some of the rules are in the wrong order, however, nothing that should prevent this from working.

Comment: @TobitheDev localhost/mrdigital/alias-links-pdf - this is presumably a WordPress page? 
yes, that`s right! This is a wp page. ::::
What if you request /mrdigital/wp-content/themes/astra-child/pdf.php?key=1360 directly? 
yes, I can download the file directly through the browser. It works

Comment: it was my fault. the page is working `localhost/mrdigital/alias-links-pdf`, and I have the same setting in the `.htaccess` that you suggest me, but the anchor in the page to the PDF files are still not working. When I click on the link I got the 404 error page. 
`https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-one">` :: `https://localhost/mrdigital/pdf-two">`::
[Please see the screenshot](https://imgur.com/BR24j56)

Comment: Object not found!

Comment: what step should i take now? did you see the error image via the link?